# How can I filter which files are included in a workspace using MSBuild?

Tags: msbuild, msbuild-task

It seems that MsBuild creates a folder called, "BuildType" on the build server and this folder is where the .proj file is copied. In source control I have several files that are in the same folder as the build project file. I have a workspace mapped to this location.

I would like to be able to specify explicitly which files from this workspace location should be copied to the build machine.  Is this possible?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot do this on file level but if you organize your build type folder with subfolders you can cloak the folders that you want to exclude.